# CSS Transition Scale / Opacity Hover Compatibility

Tags: css, cross-browser

I have two images side by side. The goal is when you hover over them, they expand and fade in slowly (while contained in a div). When you mouse out of the hover area, they ease back into their original state.

This works great in Firefox. In Chrome and Safari, when you leave the hover area, the opacity snaps back to .4 instead of easing from 1 to .4 (works perfectly in firefox). Am I missing something?

Edit/ note: The opacity needs to fade in faster than the scaling image.

```
#img-wrapper {
    width: 1100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    height: 550px;
}

.footer-btn a {
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 63px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
}
.footer-btn {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9000;
    margin-top: 240px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #000;
    height: 63px;
    width: 400px;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
.box {
    width: 550px;
    height: 550px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
}
.box img {
    width: 556px;
    height: 556px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;

}
.footer-box {
    display: table;
    max-height: 550px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9000;
}
.footer-box .blog {
    height: 556px;
    -webkit-transition: all 10s, opacity 5s;
    -moz-transition: all 10s, opacity 5s;
    -o-transition: all 10s, opacity 5s;
    -ms-transition: all 10s, opacity 5s;
    transition: all 10s, opacity 5s;
    opacity: .4;
}

.footer-box:hover .blog {
    cursor: pointer;
    height:556px;
    width: 556px;
    transform:scale(1.15);
    -ms-transform:scale(1.15); /* IE 9 */
    -moz-transform:scale(1.15); /* Firefox */
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.15); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transform:scale(1.15); /* Opera */
    opacity: 0.9;
}

    <div id="img-wrapper">
        <div class="footer-box">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="footer-btn"><a class="btn" href=''>Button Text</a></div>
                <img class="blog" src="images/footer-splash-left.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-box" style="right:0px;">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="footer-btn"><a class="btn" href=''>Button Text</a></div>
                <img class="blog" src="images/footer-splash-right.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are pointing at two different css properties in your transition, so there is conflict between the browser rendering "all 10s" and "opacity 5s"

If you wrap your image within a div and give that div a class that contains all your opacity styles, things should work.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/q3RNS/

```
<div class="opacityWrapper">
<img class="blog" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="">
</div>

.opacityWrapper{
   -webkit-transition:opacity 5s;
    -moz-transition:opacity 5s;
    -o-transition:opacity 5s;
    -ms-transition:opacity 5s;
    transition:opacity 5s; 
    opacity:.3;
}

.footer-box:hover .opacityWrapper{opacity:.9;}
```

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to mention that the opacity needs to ease in/ out faster than the scale. That's what is making it tricky for me.

Comment: If you wrap your image in a div and give that an opacity and have it fire on .footer-box:hover it should work.

I removed the opacity styles and added them to a class called opacityWrapper. Here's a fiddle;

http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/q3RNS/

Comment: THANK YOU!!! I guess my problem was trying to keep everything strung together. This works perfectly! Kudos!!